# Convert MineSight (*.msr) files to Shapefiles or Feature classes

Tags: shapefile, convert

How would I convert the MineSight (*.msr) files to Shapefiles.

MineSight files are used in MineSight Software which is used for creating block models in 3D.

Comment: Did you mean MineSight by Mintec? I don't know much about the software, but it appears that it can import shapefiles. So by any chance is there an option to export as shapefiles?

Comment: Yes you are right its MineSight by Mintec. I've no experience in this software, I was provided a MSR file and asked to convert it to Shapefile. I was told software doesn't have functionality to export it as Shapefiles. That's d reason i'm looking for alternatives if available.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the .msr file or one similar to it?

Comment: @Paul Can you let me know how can I attach the file for you. Thanks.

Comment: You need to host it somewhere else and post the link here. You could use dropbox, google drive, etc.

Comment: @Paul, Here is the link https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0PYbeGpDfZBeExMelZOR3RZNG8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Minesight does export shapefies; also recall that dxf files are always a valid alternative.

Other file formats are less common, hence difficult to handle; however mapinfo can import srg files, not msr as far as I know.

To export from minesight, just right click on the linear feature (material) in minesight and select appropriate export filter. I was working with such exported files quite a while, it works.

Comment: It is possible to import the attribute information also along with Block models.

Answer (score 0):

Current MS3D can export DXF, Shapefiles, DTM, ASCII, and a number of other formats.